# Import PNG files with built-in name in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

There is a list of hunderds of PNG images with names consisting only of 2 letters, example **aa.png, ab.png, ac.png**, etc.

There is an endpoint which returns an array of object having a property name which has 3 letters, first 2 being the same letters as from the PNG images, example:

```
[{ name: 'aax', ... }, { name: 'aby', ... }, { name: 'acq', ... }, ... ]
```

I will map through this array, for each element it will be a component that will show some info for that specific object and it should also show the images with the same first 2 chars.

Here is my implementation:

```
import React from 'react';

import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
const MyComponent = (data) => {
  const flag = `../flags/${data.name.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase()}.png`;
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <div>
        <div>Info: {data.info}</div>
        <img src={flag} alt='this is a flag' />
      </div>
    </ListItem>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

It doesn't take any image, don't know why. All those images are situated in that flags folder.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you do the following: `<img src="../flags/aa.png"/>`  ,  is an image being rendered?

Comment: @omercotkd still not working

Comment: Why not use something simpler like [react-world-flags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-world-flags)?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to use `require`.
Can you use:

```
const flag = require(`../flags/${data.name.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase()}.png`);
```

Comment: It will work but the photos have to be inside the `src` directory or it will raise an error

Comment: it works. it is a way to check if that image exists? because there are some names that don't have their flag pair, in that case I would think that it should show a default flag, for example ab.png

Comment: it returns error if the flag doesn't exist: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './xe.png'

Comment: I think using `try` and `catch` should do the trick